# How to toggle a menu when clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a `Navbar` component where I have created a hamburger menu, when I click on the hamburger menu I want to show the menu component, which is a separate component.

I got this working by sharing the data through props.

However, I want the menu to disappear when you click outside the container or when you click on a link.

Clicking outside container works with the npm package `react-outside-click-handler` but my menu does not close when I click on a link.

This is what I have currently

// navbar

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [hamburgerOpen, setHamburgerOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleHamburger = () => {
    setHamburgerOpen(!hamburgerOpen);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.hamburger + ' cursor-pointer'} onClick={toggleHamburger}>
              <span className={styles.hamburgerLine}></span>
              <span className={styles.hamburgerLine}></span>
      </div>
      <OutsideClickHandler
          onOutsideClick={() => {
            setHamburgerOpen(hamburgerOpen = false);
          }}
      >
       <Menu hamburgerStatus={hamburgerOpen} />
     </OutsideClickHandler>
    </div>
  )
}
```

// menu

```
export default function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.hamburgerStatus ? styles.menuContainer : 'hidden'}>
        <nav className='bg-secondary text-white w-full max-w-[440px] mt-6 absolute'>
            <div className="">
                <div className='flex items-center rounded p-3 cursor-pointer transition-all'>
                    <Link href="/" onClick={props.hamburgerStatus = false}>
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='flex items-center rounded p-3 cursor-pointer transition-all'>
                    <Link href="/contact">
                        Contact
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='flex items-center rounded p-3 cursor-pointer transition-all'>
                    <Link href="/contact">
                        Contact
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using `onClick={props.hamburgerStatus = false}` doesn't work, because props is not overwritable.

So what I want is the following:

Hamburger menu needs to opens `<Menu />` component when the user clicks on the hamburger menu. Clicking outside the menu component or on a link must close the menu.

How can I get this to work in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the menu when clicking on a link/navigating to another page, you can add a listener on the `next/router`'s [`routeChangeStart`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents) event, and set the `hamburgerOpen` state variable to `false` when it fires. This ensures the menu always closes on client-side navigations.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Navbar() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [hamburgerOpen, setHamburgerOpen] = useState(false);

    const closeHamburger = () => {
        setHamburgerOpen(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', closeHamburger);

        return () => router.events.off('routeChangeStart', closeHamburger);
    }, [router.events]);

    // Rest of the component's code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution but what if it's a onepager? Are there other solutions to cover one page websites?

Comment: I can use the `hashChangeStart` instead of `routeChangeStart`. Thanks @juliomalves